# Fireplace goes on/off

Tags: fireplace

Our fireplace turns on fine, runs for a while and then all of a sudden goes out, then sometimes comes back on. We usually turn it off when it happens. We have had a fireplace company out they replaced the thermocouple and it still continues. We have also had the fireplace cleaned, venting was resealed and it still continues. Our local fireplace company is stumped and we are too! We really enjoy using this and now I have turned it off as we don't know what's going on and don't feel safe using it till we know and fix it.

Comment: Who makes it and what model is it?  A picture of the innards (the gas value) may help as well.

Comment: Also, there are only so many parts to these things, the fireplace company is either trying to sell you a new one or is incompetent.  A good plumber should be able to fix it too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You will need to give us more to go on. How is it that it goes out and comes back on? Give this some thought&conjecture. Does it have a pilot light? Is it electric ignition? What about the controls? If it is pilot light driven, it isnt going to turn itself back on if there is a gas issue since you'd expect the pilot to go out. If it is an electrical safety shutoff, this can be tested with a meter. How do you "turn it off"? Gas shutoff valve? It's possible you just have near-dead batteries in your electronic control receiver. Have you tried fresh batteries?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue.  There is a pilot light. Runs on LP.  Pilot does not go out but the flames go out and then in a little bit it comes back on.  No other light switches are being turned on/off and there is no battery in the unit.  We found that when it is turned at a lower setting it happens far more often.  But it will go from flames 8 inches high to off in 1 second and then after about 2-3 minutes it comes back on.

If we turn it to a higher setting the problem goes away and the fireplace stays lit.  Because the pilot doesn't go out we know it's not air in the lines or a main regulator issue.

Comment: [Edit] your post to remove the first paragraph, then highlight the (now) second paragraph to indicate something like "Our solution was:" and you'll be good to go! This is far better as an answer than a comment, so you're OK with that and you're likely to get enough points to comment from one good answer. Welcome to [diy.se] and take the [tour] when you're done with your edit. It'll help you learn your way around here.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a condition where the control wiring for the fireplace is run through the same drilled holes in the floor joist, etc. as the standard house wiring are run through.  When a light is turned on or off or the microwave is started, this current drawn so close to the control wires can induce enough voltage in these wires to disrupt and or start the fireplace independent of thermostat control. Fully separate all control wiring from other wiring by at least 2-feet (perpendicular runs are OK).  I have seen this fix this problem.

Comment: definitely possible, but I'd still lean towards dead batteries as I've seen that more than once.